# iOS: can't change duration time when using animateTransition method

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I need help for making the circle transition.

I looked through your [article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app) and try to change swift to object-c project.

When I use the Animation Controllers, problem occurred.

At using my MaterialCircleAnimator.m:

```
#import "MaterialCircleAnimator.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@implementation MaterialCircleAnimator


- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{
    return 2.5;
}


- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{
    self.transitionContext = transitionContext;
    UIView* containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    ViewController *fromViewController = (ViewController *)    [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)];
    UIViewController *toViewController = (UIViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)];
    UIButton* button = fromViewController.button;

    [containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];

    UIBezierPath* circleMaskPathInitial = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:
                                       button.frame];
    CGPoint extremePoint = CGPointMake([button center].x, [button center].y -  CGRectGetHeight(toViewController.view.bounds));
    CGFloat radius = sqrt(extremePoint.x * extremePoint.x) + (extremePoint.y * extremePoint.y);
    UIBezierPath* circleMaskPathFinal = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:
    CGRectInset(button.frame, -radius, -radius)];
    CAShapeLayer* maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
    maskLayer.path = circleMaskPathFinal.CGPath;
    toViewController.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    CABasicAnimation* maskLayerAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    maskLayerAnimation.fromValue = (__bridge id)(circleMaskPathInitial.CGPath);
    maskLayerAnimation.toValue = (__bridge id)([circleMaskPathFinal CGPath]);
    maskLayerAnimation.duration = [self transitionDuration: transitionContext];
    maskLayerAnimation.delegate = self;

    [maskLayer addAnimation:maskLayerAnimation forKey:@"path"];

}

-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{
    [self.transitionContext completeTransition:![self.transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    [self.transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey].view.layer.mask = nil;
}

@end
```

And MaterialCircleAnimator.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MaterialCircleAnimator : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning> transitionContext;

@end
```

I found my code can't change the animation duration time.

The circle animation would last default 0.3 second no matter what NSTimeInterval I change.

Comment: That's the refer project I download
http://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/CircleTransitionFinalUpdated.zip

And my project on Github:
https://github.com/TindleWei/MaterialCircleAnimation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did minor mistake while calculating radius.

Your code:

```
CGFloat radius = sqrt(extremePoint.x * extremePoint.x) + (extremePoint.y * extremePoint.y);
```

replace new code :

```
CGFloat radius = sqrt((extremePoint.x * extremePoint.x) + (extremePoint.y * extremePoint.y));
```

actually you have not keep bracket after making square of X and Y object so there will be wrong calculation of radius.

According to formula, we need to do square root after making square of X and Y coordinate.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank u so much. The problem fixed. That's my foolish mistake at transforming swift to object-c.